# How to combine classes in Java

Tags: java, android, class, extends

I have an Android app with an Activity, a Thread and a class to hold data.

I have created an abstract class ActivityTemplate which extends the Activity class and implements some callbacks, e.g. onTouchListener. This also includes some abstract methods.
I have created an abstract class (ThreadTemplate) which extends the Thread class and includes some abstract methods.
I have created an abstract DataTemplate class which holds some data elements and some simple methods to manipulate it.

I can produce my app by deriving three classes, one from each of the 'Template's above, but I really want to be able to roll them all up into a single MyTemplate class from which I can derive my app from.

Sort of:

```
public class MyTemplate extends ActivityTemplate, ThreadTemplate, DataTemplate
```

then

```
public class MyApp extends MyTemplate
```

But the MyTemplate class will not compile as you can only extend one class.

Any thoughts, or am I asking the impossible?

Answer (score 3):

Use object composition instead of inheritance:

```
class MyApp {
    private ActivityTemplate activityTemplate;
    private ThreadTemplate threadtemplate;
    private DataTemplate dataTemplate;
}
```

When using inheritance always ask yourself the question whether your subclass has an "is-a" relationship with the parent. In this case, `MyApp` is *not* a template. It has-a template.

Comment: Thanks the the response but I don't see how will this let me implement the abstract methods in all three classes without having separate files?